# How do I pass parameters from a form redirect to a controller?

Tags: forms, redirection, page-controller

I feel like it should be easier to find this stuff out. I'm trying to pass some data from a form submission to a controller, and do something based on that data. What is the most *Drupal* way to do this (i.e. without accessing the request object directly)?

The form in a custom module that extends `FormBase` has this method.

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $var_to_send = $form_state->getValue('val_to_get'); 
    $form_state->setRedirect('my.route', [ 'sent_var' => $var_to_send ]);
}
```

In this case, my.route is configured like this.

```
my.route:
  ...
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\custom_module\Controller\MyController::index'
    ...
```

I have the following method in \Drupal\custom_module\Controller\MyController.php.

```
public function index() {
    $params = \Drupal::request()->query->all();
    $this->myfunc($params['sent_var']);
}
```

[This page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3Arequest/8.2.x) says that what I'm doing is highly discouraged. So how should I access URL parameters in a controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a route callback like a controller you can pull the request with a typed function parameter:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

  public function index(Request $request) {
    $query_parameters = $request->query->all();

  }
```